# NXT software V2.1 runtime installation error in windows

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, software

My system configuration: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit Service Pack 1.

When I try to install NXT software v2.1, I immediately get the error below:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ runtime 

Runtime Error 

program: D: Nxt/setup.exe

This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. 
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I had the same problem in Win XP also. Let me know how to fix this issue, please.

Comment: It sounds like you have the wrong NXT release.  Where did you get that v2.1?  Can you give the link?

Comment: You could also try updating Microsoft Visual. A lot of people have this problem for various Windows applications.